# select trazendo todos os registros não duplicados baseados em uma unica coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, mysqli, sql-select

Como posso trazer todos os registros de uma coluna que não sejam repetidos. Por exemplo:

```
|   tela  |    url    |     perfil     |      dataCriacao    |
---------------------------------------------
|   dica  |   /dica/  |    ROLE_CDL    | 2019-07-05 09:00:00 |
|   dica  |   /dica/  | ROLE_MARKETING | 2019-07-05 09:00:00 |
| monitor | /monitor/ |    ROLE_CDL    | 2019-07-05 09:00:00 |
```

Nesta tabela como eu poderia fazer um SELECT * FROM que eliminasse os registros duplicados da coluna `tela` e que me retornasse:

```
|   tela  |    url    |     perfil     |      dataCriacao    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   dica  |   /dica/  |    ROLE_CDL    | 2019-07-05 09:00:00 |
| monitor | /monitor/ |    ROLE_CDL    | 2019-07-05 09:00:00 |
```

Já tentei realizar um select distinct, porém não obtive sucesso.

Comment: `select DISTINCT tela from sua_tabela` não funcionou?

Comment: Tentou a função **ROW_NUMBER** ?                          `with CTE_RN as
(
    select 
  tela,
  url,
  perfil,
  dataCriacao,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tela ORDER BY tela DESC) as RN -- Função ROW_NUMBER CRIA UMA NUMERAÇÃO PARA CADA REC QUE SE REPETE 
       from  Table_1
)

select * from CTE_RN 
where RN = 1`

Comment: @Tmilitino ele funcionaria se eu quisesse somente as telas aí eu poderia dar `select distinct tela from nomedatabela`, mas eu preciso pegar o resgistro inteiro. e não só o campo tela.

Comment: se funciona, então tu pode fazer `select DISTINCT tela, url, perfil, dataCriacao from sua_tabela` ai retorna o restante dos campos

Comment: Não posso fazer isso, porque esta é uma query JPA, então precisava retornar todos os dados certinhos, para o binding ocorrer corretamente e ele já armazenar como objeto, se eu colocar campo por campo  JPA me retorna um array e aí acaba me quebrando. Creio que terei que remover os duplicados no servidor.

Comment: entendi agora tua bronca. é bom tu colocar isso na pergunta, pq da a entender que é  uma dúvida só de sql e tal, mas tem muito mais coisa envolvida.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tenta isso.

```
SELECT * FROM nome_tabela
WHERE tela NOT IN (
    SELECT tela FROM nome_tabela
    GROUP BY tela
    HAVING Count(*) > 1
)
```

Ou pode tentar isso

```
SELECT tela FROM nome_tabela
        GROUP BY tela
        HAVING Count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentou a função ROW_NUMBER ?

```
  with CTE_RN as
 (
select 
    tela,
    url,
    perfil,
    dataCriacao,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tela ORDER BY tela DESC) as RN -- Função 
   ROW_NUMBER CRIA UMA NUMERAÇÃO PARA CADA REC QUE SE REPETE 
         from  Table_1
     )

  select * from CTE_RN 
   where RN = 1;
```